# How to remove meta viewport from a dotnetnuke theme?

Tags: css, dotnetnuke

My company just buy a really nice theme for dotnetnuke. The problem comes when our clients does not want to see the site in a responsive mode. I have been thinking the problem is the meta viewport in the theme.
I dont want to create a new theme and I dont want to use javascript.
How could I remove that meta viewport from an existing theme for dotnetnuke? Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open up the ASCX files for the Theme.

Try navigating to /portals/_default/skins/THEMENAME

Locate the ASCX files there.

Make a backup before you make any edits.

Open the ASCX file in a text editor (Visual Studio works, or even just Notepad).

Locate the viewport tag, remove it.

Refresh the browser/site where you are using the theme.

If you have multiple ASCX files in there, there are likely different layouts available, and you'll probably have to edit them all.